# Test open graph actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to test open graph verbs and actions right now?

I am not able to submit the actions and objects for approval. Does that mean I won’t be able to test the flows until timeline releases?

Answer (score 4):

Your app's developer and tester accounts should be able to publish actions as far as I'm aware

Comment: when i posts actions i'm pretty sure its successful and i see the action id, but i dont see it in my news feed

Comment: They almost certainly won't appear there, but should be in the ticker at the right hand side - i'm not sure if you need to enable timeline on your profile to see them, you might